# Utilização de variáveis dentro do método onPostExecute

Tags: android

Estou usando AsyncTask no meu projeto e acabou me gerando uma duvida na passagem das variáveis, no método `doInBackground` eu retorno uma variável cursor que é passado pelo return. Queria saber qual é a obrigatoriedade de usar o return, pois se eu passar a return como nulo ainda posso usar minha variável no método `onPostExecute`. Eu posso fazer igual o exemplo abaixo:

```
public class SearchGeocode extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Cursor> {
        public Cursor minhaVariavel;
        public Boolean verifica;

        protected Cursor doInBackground(String... countryTitle) {

        minhaVariavel = SqliteDatabase;

        verifica = false;

        return null;
        }

         protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursort) {
                super.onPostExecute(cursort);

        adapSerchView = new AdapSerchView(context, minhaVariavel, 0);

        if (verifica){
        //Faça Algo
        }

        }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não é obrigado a passar como return, as duas formas são válidas.

Se tivesse mais de uma variável para passar (situação pouco comum, mas acontece) teria que usar a forma sem return, que é mais fácil de compreender do que usar ambas as formas ao mesmo tempo. Portanto você pode escolher dentre as duas formas a que mais lhe aprouver.

Você omite a necessidade de usar o retorno passando como tipo paramétrico genérico o tipo `Void` no lugar de `Cursor`.

Comment: Outra coisa no metodo onPostExecute posso chamar novamente a mesma AsyncTask?

Comment: Depende. Só se for outra instância, a mesma instância só é executada uma vez. Mas pense bem se é isso que você precisa, porque querer rodar duas AsyncTasks em sequência pode ser indício de ter uma intenção errada de implementação (por exemplo, poderia retrabalhar isso para usar somente uma AsyncTask no lugar).

Comment: Sim entendi. Obrigado.